# Windows 7 formatting HD

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have an Acer Aspire 5610 that I am trying to put an Operating System back on. I am trying to install windows 7 32-bit and it will not go through the install. Not sure why. I am now trying to reformat the hard drive and start with a fresh formatted HD. No other partitions. The problem is that the install disk is not doing the format it is giving me an error. The error is 0x8007045d. I am at a loss. This is the first time running into this issue.

Please Help.

Comment: What filesystem are you trying to use when formatting? NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

A corrupt burn process of the ISO (if that is what you did) or a corrupt ISO file used to make the burned DVD can cause this error also.

Clean the DVD, then:

Put to DVD in another PC with a know good DVD drive and see if you can do a copy and paste of all the files on the CD to the hard drive, see if you get any errors.

If no errors then try the reinstall again, if you get errors, the DVD is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Googling the error code indicates that it is or may be an I/O error. Hardware-related to the DVD drive. Do you have a chance to change the drive? Or at least test the DVD on a different PC?